# Using SQL query new feature with loop in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, sql, query, loop

I'm trying to create an individual buffer feature class for each column of an input feature class, where there is a field that contains the buffer distance.

I think there is a problem with my SQL statement because in the inner loop to access the field with the buffer length I get this error:

> for buf in loop2:
>
> RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Any suggestions? Note I also tried: query = ' "UNIQUEID" = '  + str(id[0])

Here is my code:

```
###loop through field value of nest number, AKA "UNIQUEID"

fc1 = BEN_input
field1 = "UNIQUEID"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1, (field1)) as loop1:

    for id in loop1:

        #extract out individual nest
        query = "UNIQUEID" + "="  + str(id[0])

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(BEN_input, "BEN", query)

        ##clip water to buffer size

        #access buffer size
        fc2 = "BEN"
        field2 = "best_buf"

        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc2, (field2)) as loop2:
            for buf in loop2:
                water_buf_size = buf

        #buffer nest
        arcpy.Buffer_analysis(BEN, "BEN_buf", water_buf_size)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always encourage to use [field delimiters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018v0000006p000000) to access the fields in a right way:

```
field_name = "UNIQUEID"
input_value = 5
sql_exp = """{0} = {1}""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('c:/data/file_gdb.gdb', field_name),input_value)
print sql_exp

>>> 'UNIQUEID=5'
```

Another way to do this is to use the str.format():

```
sql_exp = """{0} = {1}""".format(field_name,input_value)
>>> 'UNIQUEID = 5'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable water_buf_size is outside the scope of the Buffer_analysis. You need create the variable outside the SearchCursor, then assign the variable within the SearchCursor so it can then be accessed for the Buffer_analysis....also I would add a where clause to the search cursor where water_buf_size is not null so you only get the features that have a value.

Comment: Not only is water_buf_size outside scope, it's set zero, one, or more times to a row, without actually ever being used.