# How to replace field name with a variable in exported whereclause?

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap

In the select by attribute how do I replace `"AADT"`, with a predefined string variable?

I don't understand the pattern in `"\"AADT\">="` , can you please explain why is it that way when exported from arcMap model builder?

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inFeatures,"NEW_SELECTION","\"AADT\" >="+str(minval)+ "AND \"AADT\" <"+str(maxval))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "\" is an [escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18886596/replace-all-quotes-in-a-string-with-escaped-quotes) which is used to be able to use the quotes (" symbol) in the query.

Read here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149676/14435 about using field delimiters (will fix the right quotes if any) and use Python [str.format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format) for cleaner code . In your case, the string would be something like:

```
var_name = "AADT"
where_query = """ "{0}" >= {1} AND "{0}" < {2}""".format(var_name,str(minval),str(maxval))
```

Comment: I noticed if you use three quotes you don't need to put "\" before quotes within the string .

Comment: your where_query is invalid :( @Alex Tereshenkov

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to use the formatting for the variable name; have edited my answer.