# Using variable in Arcpy select analysis

Tags: arcpy, select, error-000358

I need to use `arcpy.Select_analysis()` in my arcpy script, but I have problem with using variables. When I use hard coded values in where_clause, it is working.

```
where_clause = '"Area" > 20'
arcpy.Select_analysis("input", "output", where_clause)
```

When I try to use variables in where_clause because user of toolbox will enter name of field and value of minimimum area, there is always problem with invalid expression. I tried lots of types of expressions, but nothing is working.

```
field_area = "Area"
minimum_area = 20
where_clause = 'field_area > minimum_area'
arcpy.Select_analysis("input", "output", where_clause)
```

Error:

> Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File "c:\program files
>   (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 98, in Select 
>   raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression field_area >
>   minimum_area Failed to execute (Select).

I work in ArcMap 10.2.

Comment: where_clause = '"' + field_area + '" > ' + str(minimum_area)

Comment: It is still not working.Same error is there: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression "Area" > 20 Failed to execute (Select). But the expression in error message seems to be correct - "Area" > 20.

Comment: You probably need to enclose the whole statement with `'`. Not tested, but try this: `where_clause = '"' + field_area + '" > ' + "'" + str(minimum_area) + "'"`

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the data format being queried -- different query engines have different required fomats.

Comment: Don't mess up with those strings - use the arcpy field delimiters http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm , sample here http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/149676/14435

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're not using variables in your query. Instead you're using strings that happen to be the same as your variable names.

What you want is:

```py
field_area = 'Area'
minimum_area = 20
where_clause = '{} > {}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters('input', field_area), minimum_area)
arcpy.Select_analysis("input", "output", where_clause)
```

Of course, that's assuming that 'input' is the name of your feature class--as in your supposedly working example above. However, I would strongly recommend that you assign the feature class name to a variable instead:

```py
field_area = 'Area'
minimum_area = 20
fcInput = 'ThePathAndOrNameOfMyFeatureClass'
fcOutput = 'ThePathAndOrNameOfTheOutputFeatureClass'
where_clause = '{} > {}'.format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fcInput, field_area), minimum_area)
arcpy.Select_analysis(fcInput, fcOutput, where_clause)
```

Comment: +1 for using .format -- String math is too convoluted when true formatting is available.  I wish I could give another plus-up for non-ambiguous variable naming.